# how to make changes in header and footer and automatically the changes will be done in all pages of the website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I can make a same header and footer in all the page of the website and if a change header and footer it will change in all the pages automatically ...?

Comment: To not re-invent the wheel, you'll need a frontend or backend templating framework

Answer (score 0):

Write Header and Footer code in separate PHP files, then import header and footer files in all the web pages

Answer (score 0):

you should write a render function.  Here's how they do it in CS50:

$values is basically a dictionary of key/value pairs.

```
function render($template, $values = array()){
// if template exists, render it

    if (file_exists("../views/$template")){

      // extract variables into local scope
      extract($values);

      // render header_form
      require("../views/header_form.php");

      // render template
      require("../views/$template");

      // render footer
      require("../views/footer.php");
    }else{
      // else err
      trigger_error("Invalid template: $template", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's CS50...?

Comment: The most popular computer course on the planet